# How to fix 'Concurrent writes on cassandra lists issue when data in the lists is getting mixed'..?

Tags: java, list, cassandra

**I have written a java program to perform upsert operation on my cassandra db which consist of a table having multiple list and using my java code i am trying to write to many such lists at the same time suppose a 10 write at a moment, but when i view my cassandra table the values in the lists are not getting stored in a synchronized way a few of the values switch their place from their original position though the timestamp is correct regarding each value but somehow the list is not represented in a correct order. Sharing files and sample code that would be helpfull to identify the issue.**

```
String newInsertQuery1 =  "UPDATE events.generated_event SET attributes = ['100'] + attributes, channels = ['100'] + channels, " + "event_types = ['100'] + event_types, ip = ['100'] + ip, library_info = ['100'] + library_info, property_ids = ['100'] + property_ids," + "texts = ['100'] + texts, user_agent = ['100'] + user_agent WHERE profile_id = '1111' AND project_id = '5bbc83f4bf52016962b695da' AND bucket_id = 1555977600000"; 

String newInsertQuery2 =  "UPDATE events.generated_event SET attributes = ['300'] + attributes, channels = ['300'] + channels, " + "event_types = ['300'] + event_types, ip = ['300'] + ip, library_info = ['300'] + library_info, property_ids = ['300'] + property_ids," + "texts = ['300'] + texts, user_agent = ['300'] + user_agent WHERE profile_id = '1111' AND project_id = '5bbc83f4bf52016962b695da' AND bucket_id = 1555977600000";

String newInsertQuery3 =  "UPDATE events.generated_event SET attributes = ['400'] + attributes, channels = ['400'] + channels, " + "event_types = ['400'] + event_types, ip = ['400'] + ip, library_info = ['400'] + library_info, property_ids = ['400'] + property_ids," + "texts = ['400'] + texts, user_agent = ['400'] + user_agent WHERE profile_id = '1111' AND project_id = '5bbc83f4bf52016962b695da' AND bucket_id = 1555977600000";
```

similarly query 4, 5, 6 ,7.

I Have made many threads that run at the same time and each thread execute a single query.

**expexted result:**

```
 profile_id   | 1111
 project_id   | 5bbc83f4bf52016962b695da
 bucket_id    | 1555977600000

 anonymous_id | 150698a7-5d02-f634-3c8d-4d7bf615f13e

 attributes   | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 channels     | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 event_types  | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 ip           | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 library_info | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 property_ids | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 texts        | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

 timestamps   | null

 user_agent   | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']
```

**Actual Result:**

```
 profile_id   | 1111
 project_id   | 5bbc83f4bf52016962b695da
 bucket_id    | 1555977600000
 anonymous_id | 150698a7-5d02-f634-3c8d-4d7bf615f13e

attributes   | ['300', '700', '500', '400', '800', '600', '00']

channels     | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '800', '500', '00']

event_types  | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

ip           | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

library_info | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

property_ids | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']

texts        | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '800', '500', '00']

timestamps   | null

 user_agent   | ['300', '700', '400', '600', '500', '800', '00']
```

[The image attached consist of the output of the sstabledump command and as you can see the tstamp are same for values say 800 in each row but when i perform a read on this table the values printed to me are not sorted out they are printed in the same order as written in sstabledump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBjnv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using multiple queries on the same row issued by different threads, you can't guarantee that the updates will be performed in specific order.

Comment: well that's true and i am not even concerned with a specific order but as u saw in my actual result consider a scenario where i am trying to store a specific object at an index of a list and when i try to reconstruct that object again it is not possible as the values are getting mixed as u can see the value 400 among all only one value has changed its index and that is what i don't want. My ideal result is my expected result please help me understand what i am doing wrong or is their any limitation.

Comment: it's very hard to guarantee particular order in distributed system. I suggest that you try to change the approach to this problem.

Comment: i would request you to please have a look of the image that i have attached as it contains the output of the sstabledump and it clearly showcase that the timestamp are same but when i retrieve the data then why it is not coming in the right order, it is being displayed in the same order as in the sstabledump but not according to the timestamp.

Comment: Timestamp is defining who is winning when you write data, but you need to look to the UUIDs in the lists - these UUIDs are defining the order of elements in the list. For example, for `attributes` you can see `4d22a6fe-...` for value 800, and for value 600 it is `4d22a6ff-...` meaning that the value 600 is next in the list

Comment: so i am supposing here that timestamp has nothing to do with the order of elements in the list as u explained earlier, can u suggest me a different approach using which i can solve my usecase.

Comment: It's very hard to say something specific based on the existing description - it's better to make step back and understand business requirements, and start from them.

Comment: is there a relation between the UUIDs and the timestamp or are they totally independent of each other..?

Comment: UUID defines index in the list, while timestamp defines the "version" of the item

Comment: Are these UUIDs generated randomly or do they follow any order becacause as I can see thier is no specific order?

Comment: I don't remember the exact algorithm of their generation, but you can see the order in them - watch changes in the first 8 characters of UUID

Comment: Please have a look of one of my problem, i need to find its solution  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56106669/11432290