# How to fix 'Concurrent writes on cassandra lists issue..?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cassandra

Suppose i consider an example of two states i.e Rajasthan, Maharashtra and two cities i.e jaipur and Mumbai respectively now if i want to store this data in the format as rajasthan, jaipur and maharashtra, mumbai in a list in cassandra and then again i try to retreive this data and i get rajasthan, mumbai and maharashtra, mumbai which is what i dont want and i just checked the sstable the timestamp for maharashtra and mumbai are same and for rajasthan and jaipur it is same then why are they not being displayed in the right order.

Comment: what is the data type of the column you are saving "rajasthan, jaipur and maharashtra, mumbai" into?

Comment: Could you provide a small code example that can be reproduced?

Comment: I have briefly described my problem here, i would request you all to please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/55920428/11432290

Comment: The data type of the column is list in cassandra.